# How does one flag a user for potential abuse/moderation

Tags: support, moderation

This person is on a tear right now:
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/44484/embalm-you

Pretty classic shitposting, IMO. But there's nothing in the UI of their profile for me to flag them. Am I missing something? Flagging each answer doesn't seem like a viable (or at least scalable) solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I would like to ask that you be patient with new users. I can see that, while you're relatively new to Bicycles SE, you have over 30k reputation on Stack Overflow. Try to put yourself in the shoes of a new user who has never encountered the Stack Exchange format.

Stack Exchange is a different format than the typical forum that many new users are accustomed to. Users typically make posts like this because they are unaware of how the site works rather than simple carelessness or disregard for our structure. They've bounced around more casually structured forums and, at first glance, this kind of looks like one of those. Typically, they simply need to be told that they're dealing with something a little different and they're happy to oblige.

As far as your question goes...

You are not missing anything in the user's profile. As it stands, flagging each answer *is* the right way to contact a moderator about a particular user. While it may appear inefficient to a non-mod, there are a couple of good reasons for doing it that way:

1. The mods have a dashboard where we can see the entire flag history for a user. If it comes to the point of contacting a user directly and/or doling out a suspension, it is very helpful to have a list of the specific pieces of content that don't fit within the site's guidelines.
2. Flagging and/or commenting on specific answers also helps new users to learn our format, rather than punishing them simply for being an enthusiastic new user who doesn't understand how the site works.

And again, I can't stress enough how much I would prefer for us to mold a new user like this. He or she clearly has some knowledge about bicycles and is very enthusiastic about sharing that knowledge. We are a small site, but would like to grow. We've had users like this in the past who have gone on to become fantastic members of the site. Let's bias ourselves to constructive criticism rather than bringing down the mod hammer.

Answer (score 3):

To contact a moderator, flag any answer written by the user, choose "in need of moderator intervention" and write a note to the moderator with whatever you want to say.

Answer (score 2):

New user, has experience with bicycles, but not a lot with the SE format.

Admittedly SE's organisation is a lot different to the common chatty web forum, which is why there's a reminder that "Username is new, be nice" or words to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a relative newbie to bicycles.se, but I've been kicking around SE for a while.  These are poor answers, but don't seem to be made in bad faith, aren't spam or abusive and don't sound *completely* clueless.

The normal way to deal with this would be a combination of downvoting and comments, plus deleting the most clueless/wrong answers.  I haven't read through them all in comparison with their questions, just enough to make sure there's nothing R/A in them.  But maybe some of them could even be salvageable, if the user is willing to come back and edit some more details into them.

Comment: The chief problem was use of all caps, that's easy to edit with https://convertcase.net/